# Why does string.Equals work for case insensitivity by default?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I have tested the following expressions to evaluate and compare (2) strings:

```
.Where(x => x.GetAttributeValue<string>("country").Equals("United States"))
.Where(x => x.GetAttributeValue<string>("country").Equals("UNITED STATES"))
.Where(x => x.GetAttributeValue<string>("country").Equals("uniteD sTates"))
```

**NOTE:** These queries are expressions built to retrieve data using the CRM LINQ provider from its SDK.

The value of `x.GetAttributeValue<string>("country")` is exactly `United States`. *All* of the expressions above return `true`. Honestly this is fine and even great with me, but doesn't seem to hold true against the MSDN [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hkt4325%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on `string.Equals` which states:

> This method performs an ordinal (case-sensitive and culture-insensitive) comparison.

I would *expect* to have to do the following which would ignore overall casing:

```
.Where(x => x.GetAttributeValue<string>("country").Equals("UnITed sTAtes", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

Interestingly, the above always returns `false`. To me this is backwards. The default implementation is not taking into account case sensitivity, and the explicit assignment of `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` is acting like it's case sensitive and thus not matching the *exact* value of `United States`.

Why is this behavior reverse or am I misunderstanding this?

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to tell us that these queries are running on the database, thereby using the collation settings of the DB?

Comment: Indeed - `string.Equals` itself is case-insensitive, but LINQ to SQL (and similar) aren't always 100% matches for the .NET behaviour.

Comment: @spender: I was thinking the same thing, but GetAttributeValue<string>() doesn't seem like something that would convert to a server-side expression.

Comment: What @spender said. This code likely isn't even running C# string equality. Try putting `.ToList()` before the first `.Where`

Comment: @atconway, what is the type of the target upon which you are invoking these `.Where` methods?  Also, if you right-click on `Where` and go to definition, what type do you get taken to?

Comment: @CraigW. I saw that, too, but `AttributeValue` does resemble the name of a common database (anti)pattern, so he may still be relying on a helper somewhere that still uses an IQueryable to produce an expression tree for linq-to-sql.

Comment: Note that you can use `x.GetAttributeValue<string>("country") == "United States"` instead of `x.GetAttributeValue<string>("country").Equals("United States")`. In C# it gives the same. The expression trees generated if this is Linq-To-Sql should also give the same result.

Comment: @spender Sorry everyone - I should have noted. I updated the post. These queries are expressions built to retrieve data using the CRM LINQ provider from its SDK. It is not LINQ to SQL or database queries. It's `C#` code running against `CRM`.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Based on what you said, is it possible that the `.Equals()` string comparison for the `CRM C#` query has a different behavior? I tried to find it's documentation but came up with the link in my OP.

Comment: @atconway: Yes, it's basically up to the linq provider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, all LINQ expressions against CRM context is converted by LINQ provider to [QueryExpression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/gg328300(v=crm.8)). And string.Equals filter is defined there as case insensitive, so you get this result.

About your attempt with `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`, IMO it could be (and I think it is) that the provider does not support that method with a second parameter (I've tried and it does not return desired result with other comparison types either).

Comment: I think this might it. Do you have a link to the MSDN documentation that states what you mentioned about `string.Equals filter is defined there as case insensitive`? I looked at the link you provided but did not see it.

Comment: Funny, I've tried to find that but couldn't. I've tried all fetch methods: FetchXML, QueryExpressions and LINQ to CRM and they work the same: case insensitive. It just work that way))).

Comment: Here is the link to conversion to QueryExpression: [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334607.aspx).

_LINQ:  Queries are built using standard language, but internally uses QueryExpression so is limited to the features of QueryExpression._

Comment: Decompiling, I see that like you say `string.Equals` is probably not the culprit here. The _real_ component causing the behavior is most likely when the `string.Equals` statement in the query expression is translated to the _actual_ query run against `CRM`. At that time I think the `.Equals` method is being projected as a case insensitive comparison under the covers.

Comment: Found some interesting info: it looks like the [DB is the problem](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fd204abf-0f17-43ed-82d0-e0c1b2a4215d/ms-crm-2011-case-sensitive?forum=crm). Some time ago guy had the reverse problem. So if you have CRM 2011 On Premises you may fix this issue by changing collation in DB, but if you have CRM Online - you should just admit it.

Answer (score 7):

Are you using LINQ-To-Sql? If so, that code is actually building an expression tree that is then translated into SQL statements that are run on Sql Server. Sql Server, like most database engines, does not care about case by default.

If this were Linq-To-Objects, I expect you'd get different results.

Comment: I'm actually using the LINQ provider from the CRM SDK. I'll update the post to note this.

Comment: @atconway Could the CRM still be sending the command on to a database somewhere?

Comment: Under the covers the `CRM` expression will get executed against the CRM repository (which I _believe_ is ultimately backed by SQL Server). The consensus seems to be that `string.Equals` is behaving as expected, but once the query expression is translated and sent to CRM, the 'case insensitivity` behavior is executed. `string.Equals` was probably a red herring to the real culprit under the covers executing the behavior and threw me off track. I need to investigate a way to siphon out/capture the actual query ran against `CRM` so I can document something tangible.

Answer (score -2):

You may try to use

```
x.GetAttributeValue<string>("country") == "United States"
```

instead of

```
x.GetAttributeValue<string>("country").Equals("United States")
```

Comment: This wouldn't change a thing.  (Whether it's linq to objects or linq to some other query provider.)

Comment: First, yes, it *does* cost something.  It costs time and energy.  Second, if you think it costs nothing then *try it yourself* first before posting it as an answer to the question.